# by using copyfile element files cant not bind into msi package

Tags: vb.net, wix, windows-installer, file-copying

i am using wix 3.0.i have a folder name "images".so i want to copy all the files from images into msi package.when i copy all the file and install msi to another PC then it did not bind the images. And when i use simple File Element then the files bind to msi package. so what should i do,

Reply me soon

Thanking You
Samir

Comment: Your question is very confusing. For starters, it is not clear why you want to use <CopyFile> instead of the regular <File> element. Are the files you want to copy already present on the target system or not?

Comment: i want to use copy file element because i dont know how many images will store into folder.All images  files are stored into image folder.so all images are coming dynamically.

Comment: what i want that i want to create screensaver dynamic in which user can select multiple images from his PC and then one swf file automatically generate.i have created one windows form in which i have called that swf file and that images which user has uploaded.after click on generate button one msi file should generate and user can install it on his personal PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to create an application that can generate a screensaver installer that includes a number of image files selected by the user — a sort of specialized InstallShield application just for creating screensavers installers.

I would first create a **template MSI file** (with wix
    or something else) that does most of
    the work. You don't know which files the user is going to select later on, so add a placeholder component with the ID "UserSelectedFiles". Distribute this
    template MSI file with your application.

Then, when the user wants to generate a
    new installer, start by copying the
    template. Edit the copied msi so that it also installs the user selected files. You can do this with the .NET classes
    you can find in the "deployment
    tools foundation" API. This is a set of assemblies that come with wix; take a look at 
    `C:\program files\Windows Installer
    XML v3\sdk`.

I have only used the DTF API for some simple stuff, like this example which counts the File table entries in the MSI:

```
var database = new Database(@"\path\to\some\file.msi");
var list = database.ExecuteQuery("SELECT FileName FROM File");
Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
```

Your case will be a bit more complicated. You will probably have to

- generate a CAB archive that contains
  the image files with the classes you
  find in the
  `Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab`
  namespace.
- merge the CAB archive into the msi
  with `Database.Merge`
- Add new entries to the File table
  of the MSI
- Change the product code to something unique for each generated MSI
- etcetera

To get an idea of the content of an MSI file and how it can be edited, I recommend you first play around a bit with the [orca](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905) and [msidb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370083%28VS.85%29.aspx) tools.